# LEFT JOIN TABLE WITH TWO CONDITION IN MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that i want to left join, A and B. But the referrence only show with one condition.

**TABLE A**

```
 id | name
  1 | name1
  2 | name2
  3 | name3
  4 | name4
  5 | name5
```

**TABLE B**

```
id | value
 1 | 2
 2 | 4
 4 | 0
```

the table linked by "id" column and B table only have 3 rows, I want to show all of the A table record and its value (it NULL if no record with same id in B table)

this is my sql query:

```
SELECT A.*, B.* 
FROM A LEFT JOIN B 
ON A.id=B.id AND B.value<=1 
ORDER BY A.id;
```

it shows all of A table rows, but all the value is NULL:

I want to show all A table's record which value above 0

Like this:

```
id  | name  | value
1   | name1  | 2
2   | name2   | 4
3   | name3   | NULL
4   | name4   | 0
5   | name5   | NULL
```

Comment: what are you expecting to see out of your working query, given the sample data you have provided?

Comment: why you put this condition AND B.value<=1 ?

Comment: why are both [tag:mysql] and [tag:sql-server] tagged?

Comment: because i just want to show the a table that b.value is above or same with 1;

Comment: "I just want to show the A table row with value above or same with 1" - please reword this sentence, (at least) I cannot understand the point you're trying to make

Answer (score 1):

SQLFiddle is seemingly having issues when trying to build one, but given the following:

```
create table #tablea (id int, name varchar(50))
insert into #tablea (id, name)
select 1, 'name1'
union all 
select 2, 'name2'
union all 
select 3, 'name3'
union all 
select 4, 'name4'
union all 
select 5, 'name5'

create table #tableb (id int, value int)
insert into #tableb (id, value)
select 1, 2
union all 
select 2, 4
union all
select 4, 0

SELECT A.*, B.* 
FROM #tablea A LEFT JOIN #tableb B 
ON A.id=B.id AND B.value<=1 
ORDER BY A.id;

DROP TABLE #tablea
DROP TABLE #tableb
```

Your posted query:

```
SELECT A.*, B.* 
FROM #tablea A 
LEFT JOIN #tableb B 
ON A.id=B.id AND B.value<=1 
ORDER BY A.id;
```

would return:

```
id  name    id      value
----
1   name1   NULL    NULL
2   name2   NULL    NULL
3   name3   NULL    NULL
4   name4   4       0
5   name5   NULL    NULL
```

**not** all nulls as you stated.  The results it has returned are correct with the query as you've written it.

```
SELECT A.*, B.* 
FROM #tablea A 
LEFT JOIN #tableb B 
ON A.id=B.id AND B.value<=1 
ORDER BY A.id;
```

The above stated, select all columns from `table a` and `table b`.  `table A` should only join onto `table b` where the IDs match ***and*** the `value` is <= 1.  In the sample data you have provided, the only row that has a value of <= 1, is ID 4.  Hence, why ID 4 is the only `value` being output in your query - it's the only row from `table B` that meets your join criteria.

Now this is only an explanation of why you're getting what you're getting.  It is still not clear to me what you ***want*** to get.

Note the above is `sql-server` as one of the original tags in your post indicated - looks like it's actually `mysql` but the same ideas still apply.

Based on your edit, and the data you actually want, just change your query to this:

```
SELECT A.*, B.* 
FROM A LEFT JOIN B 
ON A.id=B.id
ORDER BY A.id;
```

note, the only change is i took out `AND B.value<=1` - I don't have an idea why this was included as it's limiting your result set to something you don't want.